# Could not find class when running puppet module during Vagrant deploy

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

I'm looking to deploy a CentOS 7 VirtualBox VM by Vagrant 1.9.5 and I want to run some puppet modules deployed locally.

Below my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.hostname = "test01.virtual"         

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules/"
    puppet.options = ['--verbose']
  end
end
```

and my default.pp file under ./puppet/manifests:

```
Package { allow_virtual => true }

include mycode-dummy
```

Puppet module seems ok:

```
$ grep class puppet/modules/mycode-dummy/manifests/init.pp
class dummy($path    = '/tmp/dummy',
```

When I run vagrant up I receive the following error message:

```
....
==> default: Info: Loading facts
==> default: Error: Could not find class mycode-dummy for test01.virtual on node test01.virtual
==> default: Error: Could not find class mycode-dummy for test01.virtual on node test01.virtual
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

It happens also with other modules and with other vagrant boxes.
I didn't catch was wrong...

BR
FleX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not calling the dummy class, you include a module but do not call anything from this module.

In your  `default.pp` you need to have something like

```
Package { allow_virtual => true }

class {dummy: }

include dummy
```

Comment: ==> default: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class dummy at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015fc5f3/default.pp:9 on node test01.virtual

Comment: sorry fix a typo

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works (after i rename the module from mycode-dummy to dummy) !!!!